Trying to detect if img is overlapping cloned img
I'm trying to check if a img is hitting a cloned img but when testing it seems to be thinking its hitting the clone when it is not
 const moveInterval = setInterval(() => {
               const rect = clonedBullet.getBoundingClientRect();
               if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth) {
                   clearInterval(moveInterval); // Stop moving
                   document.body.removeChild(clonedBullet); // Delete the clone
               } else {
                   clonedBullet.style.left = (rect.left + 2) + "px"; // Move right  & detect hit
                   if (Player.y < clonedBullet.y + clonedBullet.height / 2 && Player.y > clonedBullet.y - clonedBullet.height / 2) {
                      if (Player.x < clonedBullet.x + clonedBullet.width / 2 && Player.x > clonedBullet.x - clonedBullet.width / 2) {
                          Hp = Hp - 1
                          document.getElementById("hpHeader").textContent = Hp;
                      }
                  }
             


               }
           }, 5);

I've tried to change the box where it's checking I also tried to do meany things but I have not worked on this for a pretty long time so I can't remember.

in my opinion, to help check if the image is in collision, it's best to use the getBoundingClientRect() function to get the exact position and dimensions of both Player and clonedBullet. In your given code, Player.x, Player.y, clonedBullet.x, and clonedBullet.y are being accessed directly, which may not be giving the right coordinates if these are not updated properties.
I have written down the following code:
const moveInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const bulletRect = clonedBullet.getBoundingClientRect();
    const playerRect = Player.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (bulletRect.right >= window.innerWidth) {
        clearInterval(moveInterval);
        document.body.removeChild(clonedBullet);
    } else {
        clonedBullet.style.left = (bulletRect.left + 2) + "px";

        if (
            bulletRect.left < playerRect.right &&
            bulletRect.right > playerRect.left &&
            bulletRect.top < playerRect.bottom &&
            bulletRect.bottom > playerRect.top
        ) {
            Hp -= 1;
            document.getElementById("hpHeader").textContent = Hp;
            clearInterval(moveInterval);
            document.body.removeChild(clonedBullet);
        }
    }
}, 5);

In my opinion: first we retrieve getBoundingClientRect() for both clonedBullet and Player which gives the exact position and size of both elements.
Then, a collision check is done using the four corners of both rectangles.
Finally, if there is a collision then HP is decremented, and the clonedBullet is removed to avoid further hits.
